# testing external excel output with R testthat package

Tags: r, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a function of mine with the testthat package. The function is supposed to create an excel file, and I want to test if that excel file exists and contains the things it's supposed to contain. I tried running the function to create a simple mockup excel file and then reading in the output again, but that seems to not do anything, I'm guessing because of the localized testing environment. I also feel like writing code outside of the tests is not a good idea since it gave me a warning message about it.
Is there a way to test an external output with testthat that I don't know about? I'm new to unit testing and this package so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share code / data ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this myself by accident: code run in test_that DOES produce output, just in the test folder. I could read it from there and then test.